# Why can't I programatically replace perfc009.dat in windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

We have an application that uses the Windows 7 performance counters to track the total CPU usage. Every so often the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009 will become corrupted and just be empty.

Manually following the steps found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956 works perfectly. But when I make a C# program to programatically replace the 2 files mentioned no errors, exceptions, etc. But the files are not saved to the proper directory.

Here's what I've been using to test:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileToReadPath1 = @"perfc009.dat";
        string fileToReadPath2 = @"perfh009.dat";

        FileInfo fileToRead1 = new FileInfo(fileToReadPath1);
        FileInfo fileToRead2 = new FileInfo(fileToReadPath2);

        FileInfo fileToReplaceInfo1 = new FileInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\perfc009.dat");
        FileInfo fileToReplaceInfo2 = new FileInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\perfh009.dat");

        File.Copy(fileToRead1.FullName, fileToReplaceInfo1.FullName, true);
        File.Copy(fileToRead2.FullName, fileToReplaceInfo2.FullName, true);
    }
```

I do make sure to run it with Administrative privileges.

Anyone know why the program would seem to run fine, but not copy the files to that directory? Is there some Windows security thing stopping this?

Comment: What is the bitness of the OS? of your program? There maybe issues because of file system redirection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are you running this with UAC elevation?  Required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Z and the link shared in the comments above. Turns out because I was running in a 32-bit process, the OS did not allow it to edit those files. Compiling to 64-bit did work.

Reposting the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx